# Como puedo mejorar este metodo para filtrar objetos provenientes de firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

espero me puedan ayudar.  Tengo un *input* que está capturando los valores que se ingresan y son enviados a una función la cual obtiene los objetos de mi *base de datos* para filtrarlos bajo cierto critero.

El problema que presenta este proceso, es que van quedando las llamadas activas por cada vez que se presiona un caracter. Esto origina que la aplicación, despues de un par de consultas, se degrade y  se vuelva inutilizable.

Este es el código en el que estoy trabajando

productos.component.html

```
<div class="buscar">
   <input (keyup)="filtrarProducto($event)" type="text" placeholder="Bucar Producto">
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let producto of productos | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }" (click)="rowSelected(producto)">
    <td>{{producto.stock}}</td>
</tr>
```

producto.component.ts

```
//ARRAY PARA ALMACENAR PRODUCTOS
  public productos:Producto[];
  filtrarProducto(evento:any){

    //CAPTURANDO ENTRA DEL INPUT
    let texto:string = ((<HTMLInputElement> evento.target).value);

    //OBTENIENDO TODOS LOS TRABAJADORES
    this.productoService.getProductos().subscribe((response)=>{

      //INICIALIZANDO ARRAY
      this.productos = [];

      //RECORRIENDO RESULTADO
      response.map((e)=>{
        //CREANDO OBJETO TEMPORAL OBTENIDO DE LA BD
        let prod:Producto = e.payload.doc.data() as Producto;

        //FILTRANDO
        if(
          (prod.nombre).toUpperCase().includes((texto).toUpperCase())   ||
          (prod.categoria).toUpperCase().includes((texto).toUpperCase())||
          (prod.marca).toUpperCase().includes((texto).toUpperCase())    ||
          (prod.codigo).toUpperCase().includes((texto).toUpperCase()) 
          ){
            //ALMACENANDO PRODUCTO QUE COINCIDA CON FILTRO
            //DENTRO DEL ARRAY
            prod.id = e.payload.doc.id;
            this.productos.push(prod);
        }
      });
    });
    
  }
```

producto.service.ts

```
getProductos(){
    return this.angularFirestore.collection("productos").snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Has intentado usar `debounceTime` de `rxjs`? Lo instalas con `npm install rxjs` y lo usas como `import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';` para esperar un tiempo a la función `debounceTime(1000),`

Comment: genial no conocía ese modulo, lo implementare gracias